# php mysqli bind_result returns 1

Tags: php, android, mysql, mysqli

Hello I am trying to make a login app using android and php running on an ec2 instance, but I cant login even if I put the right credentials.
So I started printing the query and if I print $user all I get is "1" any suggestions?

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id,$unique_id,$name,$email,$encrypted_password,$salt,$created_at,$updated_at);
        $user = $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();     

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are printing the return of `fetch()`, which is true/1 if successfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use bind_result, you get the data in the variables that you bind with bind_result.

```
$stmt->bind_result($id,$unique_id,$name,$email,$encrypted_password,$salt,$created_at,$updated_at);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $unique_id;
$stmt->close();
```